# Can I get the NLogViewer to display entire log file?

Tags: wpf, nlog

I have a "long-running" WPF desktop application which uses NLog and the NLogViewer to display runtime status.  It is used to monitor a database, pick up requests for processing, and then logging the results.  (Yeah -- should have been a service, but we wanted to start out this way first -- baby steps.)  The results are logged to a text log file and the NLogViewer shows the current items in the log in real time.

After the app has been running several hours, I've noticed I can only view a portion of the log -- from current entry back to an hour or so earlier.  The scrollbar lets me scroll down to the most current entry, but stops way before the first entry.  At this time, there isn't a lot of logging going on, i.e., no debugging or tracing, just Info, Warnings, and Errors, so I don't think the size of the log would have an impact.

Is there a way to have the NLogViewer let me view the entire log file or will it only show me a limited window into the log?  Is there an alternate NLog viewer WPF control?  I'm not really looking at a standalong NLog viewer at this time.  If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks!

Edit:  I had some time to revisit this issue and got the NLogViewer source from GitHub.  In the code-behind for the view, there is a hard coded value of 50 for the number of entries held in the items source for the ListView.  For each item over 50, an item is removed from the beginning of the log.  I could, of course, download the source and modify it to my liking which might be the final solution as the project hasn't been updated in 3 years.  However, I might try and see if I can create a wrapper around the original control and allow for some basic extensions such as a configurable number of log entries to display and to always show the last entry added.  If I have any success, I'll post what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a new version of the `NLogViewer`. Without any limitation. You can also change the style if you want to

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentinel.NLogViewer

https://github.com/dojo90/NLogViewer

Answer (score 0):

I spend a lot of time yesterday working on this, trying to just extend the existing class with new behaviors or properties.  The biggest issue was with the hard coded 50 entries in a protected method that I couldn't access or override.  And since the NLogViewer control is defined with XAML, I couldn't easily subclass it with a "non-XAML" class (compile errors).  In the end, it seemed simpler to just use the original source code and make some mods to get the desired results.

I made the following changes:

- I added 2 properties to the NLogViewer "view":

  ```
  [Description("Automatically scroll last entry into view?"), Category("Data")]
  public bool ScrollIntoView { get; set; } = true;

  [Description("How many log entries should be kept in memory."), Category("Data")]
  public int VisibleEntryCount { get; set; } = 50;  // Original code default
  ```

  These will control if the last log entry is scrolled into view and how many log entries will be available for display.
- I modified the existing LogReceived handler to use the VisibleEntryCount property.

  ```
  protected void LogReceived(NLog.Common.AsyncLogEventInfo log)
  {
      LogEventViewModel vm = new LogEventViewModel(log.LogEvent);

      if (this.VisibleEntryCount == 0)
      {
          this.VisibleEntryCount = 50;  // Original code default.
      }

      this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
      {
          if (this.LogEntries.Count >= this.VisibleEntryCount)
          {
              // We've reached our limit.
              this.LogEntries.RemoveAt(0);
          }

          this.LogEntries.Add(vm);
      }));
  }
  ```
- And I added a new event handler for whenever a new log entry is added.  This will let me ensure the last entry is always visible (if specified by the user).

  ```
  private void LogEntries_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      if (this.ScrollIntoView)
      {
          if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
          {
              if (this.logView != null)
              {
                  int count = this.LogEntries.Count;
                  object selectedItem = (count > 0) ? this.LogEntries[count - 1] : null;
                  if (selectedItem != null)
                  {
                      this.logView.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                      {
                          this.logView.UpdateLayout();
                          this.logView.ScrollIntoView(selectedItem);
                      }));
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

It seems to be working OK.  As always, I'm open to additional solutions or suggestions.  Thanks!